# Hibernate OneToMany relationship mapping clarification

Tags: java, hibernate

I have configured the OneToMany mappings for my tables.So when inserting values to the fisrt table on second time it gives me an error Cannot insert duplicate key row in object. Here is my tables.

Table -1 (feature_id is pk and auto generated by table) and name is inserting by me.

```
   Feature_id(PK) 
   Name
```

feature table has index

```
"GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_Name ON "dbo"."Feature"(Name)
```

Table-2 (Feature_Version_id PK and auto generated by table)

```
   Feature_Version_id ,
   Version_Name 
   Feature_id
```

POJO classes are :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FEATURE")
public class Feature {

    private int feature_id;
    private String name;
    private Set<FeatureVersion> featureversion = new HashSet<FeatureVersion>(0);

    public Feature() {
    }

    public Feature(String name ,Set<FeatureVersion> featureversion) {
        this.name = name;
        this.featureversion = featureversion;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="FEATURE_ID")
    public int getFeature_id() {
        return feature_id;
    }

    public void setFeature_id(int feature_id) {
        this.feature_id = feature_id;
    }

    @Column(name="NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="feature")
    public Set<FeatureVersion> getFeatureversion() {
        return featureversion;
    }

    public void setFeatureversion(Set<FeatureVersion> featureversion) {
        this.featureversion = featureversion;
    }
}
```

Second table POJO class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FEATURE_VERSION")
public class FeatureVersion {

    private int feature_version_id;
    private String version_name;
    private int feature_id;
    private Feature feature;
    private Set<PartFeatureVersion> partfeatureversion = new HashSet<PartFeatureVersion>(0);

    public FeatureVersion() {
    }


    public FeatureVersion(Feature feature, String version_name, int feature_id) {
        this.feature = feature;
        this.version_name = version_name;
        this.feature_id = feature_id;

    }



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="FEATURE_VERSION_ID")
    public int getFeature_version_id() {
        return feature_version_id;
    }

    public void setFeature_version_id(int feature_version_id) {
        this.feature_version_id = feature_version_id;
    }

    @Column(name="VERSION_NAME")
    public String getVersion_name() {
        return version_name;
    }

    public void setVersion_name(String version_name) {
        this.version_name = version_name;
    }


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="feature_id")
    public Feature getFeature() {
        return feature;
    }

    public void setFeature(Feature feature) {
        this.feature = feature;
    }



    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="featureversion")
    public Set<PartFeatureVersion> getPartfeatureversion() {
        return partfeatureversion;
    }



    public void setPartfeatureversion(Set<PartFeatureVersion> partfeatureversion) {
        this.partfeatureversion = partfeatureversion;
    }
}
```

Main class :

```
Session session = (Session) HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Feature feature = new Feature();
FeatureVersion featurever = new FeatureVersion();
feature.setName("stack");
session.save(feature);

featurever.setVersion_name("12.2");
featurever.setFeature(feature);
feature.getFeatureversion().add(featurever);
session.save(featurever);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.flush();
```

Here is my input values :

```
(feature id generated by table)
First attempt for first table: stack
First attempt for second table : 12.2
(feature_id come from feature table)

second attempt for first table: stack
second attempt for second table : 12.3
```

OneToMany configuration will take care if more than one values come to OneToMany releationship ? Or i need to check if value is exist then just the version name ? These all values loop through from the list. Please advise what should i do here .

Thanks,

Comment: You didn't provide the stack trace of the exception, but it seems like you're trying to insert to features with the same name, where as you have a **unique** index on the feature name. That, obviously, throws an exception. Your problem thus doesn't have anything to do with OneToMany associations. You shouldn't have a feature_id field in FeatureVersion though, since it's not mapped, and you already have a feature field. Also, your naming is terrible. Respect the Java naming conventions, and use the plural form for collections: `featureVersions` and not `featureversion`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But you didn't see **feature_id** in **Feature_Version** table. It's there the fields. Yes , i will the correct the javanaming.

Comment: The feature_id column in the table is used to materialize the OneToMany/ManyToOne between Feature and FeatureVersion. BTW, you seem to understand it since you used `@JoinColumn(name="feature_id")`. The feature_id field in the class is thus completely useless. BTW, it will always be null, since it isn't mapped.

Comment: Okay , Just followed [online tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) as given.If is this not correct , Please give me your advise.

Comment: Do you see a stock_id field in StockDailyRecord? There isn't one. The tutorial is correct. Your code isn't.

Comment: @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_ID", nullable = false) , you mean nullable=false is missing in my code  ?

Comment: No. I mean that, since you created a **unique** index on feature.name, it's perfectly normal that you get an exception when trying to insert a feature with the same name as an existing one. **unique** means: there can't be two rows with the same name.